# How to index a field in elasticsearch but not store it in _source?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a collection of documents with a text field "features", and would like to make this field indexed (so documents can be searched through the field) but not stored (in order to save disk space).

How to index a field in elasticsearch like this "features" field but not store it in _source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following index mapping, will [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) a field value but not [store](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html) it

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "features": {
        "type": "text",
        "index": "true",
        "store": "false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "features": "capacity"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "stored_fields": [
    "features"
  ]
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67155998",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0
      }
    ]
```

**UPDATE 1:**

When a field is indexed, then you can perform queries on it. If a field is stored the contents of the field can be shown when the document matches.

But if you want that the content of the field should also not to be displayed in the `_source`, then you need to disable the `_source` field.

You need to modify your index mapping as

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
      "features": {
        "type": "text",
        "index": "true",
        "store": "false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "features":"capacity"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67155998",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821
      }
    ]
```